# connect event is not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am very new to socket.io, node.js, and javascript in general. I am building a real-time web application with a partner for a summer research project.

My question: Am I able to have a 'connect' event and a 'connection' event on the server side? I have not been able to fire the connect event from the client side however I have been able to fire other event from the server side.

Secondary Question: Are 'connect'/'connection'/'disconnect' native events to the language and are there others?

Third Question: Are the 'connect' and 'connection' event the same thing?

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  console.log('user connected from: ' + socket.id);

  socket.on("connect", function(MessagePlayerName) {

    console.log(MessagePlayerName);

  });

  socket.on("disconnect", function() {

    console.log('user disconnected');

  });

});

http.listen(3000, function(){

  console.log('listenening on *: 3000');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can respond to your first and third question : yes there are the same it is written [here](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io) in the section event. So on server side you can listen one of theme.

To the second question : these event are fired by socket.io and are not JS native.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I read this on Socket.IO's website but I just wanted to be sure because my partner made the API and I know he's done this before so I wanted to have all my ducks in a row before I asked him. Again thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Socket.io is a third party libary. Please consult documation before posting here at SO.

http://socket.io